# Casting object into KeyValuePair throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net application which has a function which receives an object parameter which contain collection of key value `<string,string>`  and I want to cast these object into an keyValuePair`<string,string>.`

Here is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ProcessIT(object employeeDts1, string val)
{
      KeyValuePair<string, string> txt = new KeyValuePair<string, string>();
      txt = ( KeyValuePair<string, string>)employeeDts1 ;
      if (txt!=null)
      {
          //here I process that object...
      }
}
```

but the problem is that when I cast that object into Keyvaluepair I got the following error

> "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: What kind of "collection of key value"? Set a breakpoint and inspect it in the debugger.

Comment: If it is a collection of keyvaluepairs, why do you want to cast them as a single keyvaluepair? Maybe try this cast  ((Collection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)employeeDts1)

Comment: What is `employeeDts1`?

Comment: You can't cast any kind of collection of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` into a single `KeyValuePair<string, string>` just as you can't cast an `int[]` to an `int`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, its <string,string> type

Comment: wats the time of employeeDts1? are u fetching it from the dictionary thru an index?

Comment: @Safeena: there is no `<string,string>` type. Maybe a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` or `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` or `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>`.

Comment: If you create a proper model for the data you are receving model binding should work. Here is [one example](http://netcodeandbeyond.blogspot.se/2013/09/using-jquery-to-post-data-to-aspnet-web.html).

Answer (score 0):

You said it's a **collection of KeyValuePair**, so of course you can't cast that collection to a single instance of a KeyValuePair.

You either want to create another collection, or just take one from that collection - which is it?

```
public static string ProcessIT(object employeeDts1, string val)
{
      // cast object to concrete type, assuming collection is IEnumerable here
      // but obviously only you know what the type is
      var KvpCollection = employeeDts1 As IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>;
      if (KvpCollection == null) 
        {
           // bad data, you better handle it and not carry on
        }
      foreach (var keyValuePair in KvpCollection)
      {
        // do something to each of your keyValuePair objects ...
      }
}
```

Comment: What is this even? return; in a string function? if txt!= null? when you've said it's a KeyValuePair? Do you mean to check the Key and the Value? How do you know that it's possible to cast employeeDts1 to a IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>? and why not use a IDictionary instead?

Comment: the `txt!=null` was direct from the question ... I wasn't intending to pull apart all OP code, just give clues to how you need to cast your object which was a **collection** of KVP to another collection, not a single KVP. And no, I don't know it is IEnumerable, but the OP will (or should!) and can cast as appropriate. My answer also had a question, because of the guess of whether OP wants just a single item from `employeeDts1` or the whole lot - so treat this as an example, not your cut-and-paste solution.